# POST _viewstate with php

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to send post values using a PHP script to an external website and get the result. My code is as follows

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'drpservice' => 091,
        'drpdirection' => 1,
        'drpbusstop' => 18051
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $result;
```

However, it won't return the required results unless I can manage to send in the hidden _VIEWSTATE value. 
Anyone able to help?

Comment: _VIEWSTATE is usually for a .NET website. You'd have to replicate the .NET state serialisation system in php I guess. good luck.
They don't have a simpler api/service you can use?

Comment: Just an aside, in case you weren't aware - PHP will try to evaluate `091` as octal giving you `0`. You'd need to pass it as the literal string `"091"` or drop the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the form page using a GET request, and then you can parse the page to get the _VIEWSTATE value using a regular expression.

Then when doing the POST pass the value you got for it.